# Generate a random pattern with at-most n repeated consecutive elements

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I want to generate a random pattern which has at-most `n (>= 0)` repeated consecutive elements from a sample space. The following example explains what I mean:

Consider a sample space `{1, 2, 3, 4}`,

**`n = 0`** -> there should be no consecutive repeating element. For example,

> `{1 (*random choice from {1, 2, 3, 4}*), 3 (*random choice from {2, 3, 4}*), 4 (*random choice from {1, 3, 4}*), ...}`

**`n = 1`** -> at most 1 consecutive repeating element. For example,

> `{1 (*random choice from {1, 2, 3, 4}*), 1 (*random choice from {1, 2, 3, 4}*), 4 (*random choice from {2, 3, 4}*), ...}`

and so on.

**My attempt:**

`n = 0`

```
randN[sample_, size_] :=  NestList[
    RandomChoice[Delete[sample, #]] &, RandomChoice[sample], 
    size
];
randN[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 10]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1}

For `n >= 1`, I was using some kind of a loop and it quickly became scary. Is there an idiomatic implementation for this case (or much better including `n = 0` case)?

Comment: for `n=1`, is `{1,1,1,1,2,3,4}` allowed or the number of repetitions is limited to 2?

Comment: Does the probability of each number changes depending how many of these numbers have already been drawn?

Comment: @swish The pattern can be of any length and it grows from left to right with not more than n same consecutive elements. For example, in this sequence for `n = 1` - `{1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, ...}`. The first element, 1, is a random choice and the second element is conditional upon the first, i.e., you can have one more `1` and the third element because there was already two `1`'s, we should not pick `1`.

Comment: @kglr for `n = 1`, that sequence will not satisfy, because there are 4 consecutive `1`'s. A sequence like `{1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, ...}` would satisfy that case.

Comment: @rhermans It is conditional upon the previous element, so the probability would change.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Did I misunderstand the question? From your description I expect e.g. in kglr's answer `Max[Length /@ Split[rand3[Range@3, 200000, 5]]]` to be close `6` with high probability, but it seems to never be beyond 2.

Comment: @Coolwater It should be uniformly distributed. I mean for `n=5`, probability that no. of equal consecutive numbers being 2 should be equal to that of 4 and so on.

Comment: I'm concerned this might not be a well defined problem. You ask for a random sequence that satisfies some arbitrary "time domain" predicate. It is possible to imagine many different approaches to limiting the occurrence of n-times-repeated elements. Each method may have differing implications for the statistical characteristics of the sequence as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
rand[sample_, size_, n_] := Module[{
   rs = RandomChoice[sample, RandomInteger[{0, n}]],
   rand0},
  rand0 = 
   NestList[RandomChoice[Delete[sample, #]] &, RandomChoice[sample], 
    size - 1 - Length[rs]];
  Fold[Insert[#1, #2, RandomChoice[Position[#1, #2]]] &, rand0, rs]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is efficient and idiomatic. Interesting use of `Position`.

Comment: Interesting answer, but I would note that it seems like this algorithm very strictly requires the argument `sample` to be a list of integers 1 to n (in order). Perhaps better then to replace `sample` with `Range[m]` for a new argument `m`?

Comment: Or as a quick workaround, `mylist[[#]] & /@ rand[Range[Length[mylist]], size, n]` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Borrowing part of swish's answer to generate consecutive-free samples and using it with `Part` assignment (`rand2`) and `ReplacePart` (`rand3`):

```
ClearAll[consecutiveFreeRandom , rand2,rand3]
consecutiveFreeRandom[sample_,size_]:= NestList[RandomChoice[Delete[sample, #]] &,
    RandomChoice[sample], size-1]  

rand2[sample_, size_, n_] := Module[{rpt = RandomInteger[{0, n}], pos, rand0},
  pos = RandomSample[Range[size - rpt], rpt] ;
  rand0 = consecutiveFreeRandom[sample, size  - rpt];
  rand0[[pos]] = Transpose[{rand0[[pos]], rand0[[pos]]}]; Flatten @ rand0 ] 

rand3[sample_, size_, n_] := Module[{rpt = RandomInteger[{0, n}], pos, rand0},
  pos = RandomSample[Range[size - rpt], rpt] ;
  rand0 = consecutiveFreeRandom[sample, size - rpt] ;
  rand0 = ReplacePart[rand0, # -> Sequence[rand0[[#]], rand0[[#]] ]& /@ pos]]
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1]
rand2[Range@3, 20, 2]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = CharacterRange["A", "C"];
list[[rand2[Range @ Length @ list, 20, 2]]]
```

> {"C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B",
>    "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"}

```
SeedRandom[1]
rand3[Range@2, 30, 5]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2}

By selecting positions up to the allowed number of consecutives from the positions in the consecutive-free sample and repeating the elements in those positions, (1) `rand2` and `rand3` avoid the potential error that `rand` produces (when `Position[#, #2]` in its last line is `{}`) and (2) they are faster than `rand` when the bound on the number of consecutives is large.

```
timings = ArrayReshape[Table[{i, ss, rp, 
    First[RepeatedTiming[Quiet@rand[Range[i], ss, rp]]] , 
    First[RepeatedTiming[rand2[Range[i], ss, rp]]] , 
    First[RepeatedTiming[rand3[Range[i], ss, rp]]] }, 
  {i, {5, 100}}, {ss, {1000, 10000}}, {rp, {0, 1, 10, 500}}], {16, 6}];

timings[[All,{4, 5, 6}]] = NumberForm[#, {7, 5}]& /@ # & /@ timings[[All,{4, 5, 6}]]; 

Join[{{"input", "sample", "max number of", "timings", SpanFromLeft, 
    SpanFromLeft}, {"range", "size", "consecutives", 
    Item["rand", Frame -> True], Item["rand2", Frame -> True], 
    Item["rand3", Frame -> True]}}, table] // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> {All, {Range[25], {2 -> None}}}] &
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{}, While[Count[Differences[rc = RandomChoice[#, #2]], 0] > #3,
     rc = RandomChoice[#, #2]]; rc] &;
```

Alternatively, you can use `Total[1 - Unitize[Differences[rc = RandomChoice[#, #2]]]] > #3` in place of `Count[Differences[rc = RandomChoice[#, #2]], 0] > #3`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
f[Range@4, 10, 0]
```

> {2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1}

```
f[Range@4, 20, 2]
```

> {4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1}

Comment: Good old monkey algorithm

Comment: @swish, exactly:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems to take a lot of time to create a list size of 100.

Comment: @Anjan, yes it is slow.

Comment: @kglr `rand2[Range@3, 20, 2]` returned `{List, List}[2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, {2, 2}, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: @Coolwater, thank you. Copied the wrong block of code. Fixed now.

Comment: @kglr Thank you for your update and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Below `gen` makes a sample, splits it into sublists of repeated consecutive elements and take up to `n+1` elements from (almost) each sublist.

"almost" means "except the last sublist". The last sublist is instead prepended to the next sample so as to avoid problems when joining multiple sample (some elements are discarded, so the first sample may end up being too short).

`need` is how many elements the current joined samples lack. Because some elements are discarded, `⌈need scale⌉ + 5` is used as the next sample size. The expected size after discarding bad repetitions will not exactly be equal to `need`, but I think it's somewhat close to.

```
gen[sample_, size_, n_] := Module[{prevEnd = {}, res = {}, need = size,
                                   scale = (1 - (1/Length[sample])^(n + 1))^-1 // N},
  While[need > 0,
   (res = Join[res, Take[#, UpTo[need]]]; prevEnd = #2; need = size - Length[res]) & @@
     Join @@@ TakeList[Split[Join[prevEnd, RandomChoice[sample, ⌈need scale⌉ + 5]]],
                       {{1, -2}, 1}, {UpTo[n + 1]}][[{1, 2}, 1]];]; res]

gen[Range[2], 30, 4]
```

> {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
>   2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}